# How to dynamically download Excel files from website?

Tags: python, dynamic

I'm new to Python and in the learning process. I have an internal online portal from where I download excel reports periodically. I need to select standard attributes (from List box, checkbox, etc) in the webpage and provide my email address to get the excel report emailed.

Is there a way I can automate the file download using Python? If not Python, what other programs can be used to do it?

Comment: Of course you can use python to automate the report download. If you want to automate on user interface then you can use selenium and if you have access to api for report download u can use requests

Comment: Actually, I would not prefer selenium because it is heavy, sometimes and almost, you could look up website and API structure, reproduce download link via Postman. Then 2 libraries are used: requests, BeautifulSoup if needed for parsing HTML

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.